# Verify that the Bundle Identifier in your project is your signing id in Xcode open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I am trying to build my **flutter** app using **codemagic** and published to **testFlight**. I followed the codemagic docs and connect **Appstore connect api key** and also set "app manager" as permission. My code is successfully working in my android emulator. here is the full error log:

`It appears that there was a problem signing your application prior to installation on the device.Verify that the Bundle Identifier in your project is your signing id in Xcode
  open ios/Runner.xcworkspace.Also try selecting 'Product > Build' to fix the problem:
Error (Xcode): Provisioning profile "XC Wildcard ios_app_store 1659738754" doesn't include the com.apple.developer.applesignin entitlement.`

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: I selected wrong bundle identifier in workflow setting in codemagic while running build. The solution is to the select same bundle identifier which your flutter project has. In workflow setting under build options, when you click on bundle identifier it will show you all bundle identifier listed in appstore. you need to select your flutter project has.

Comment: I selected "XC Wildcard" as bundle identifier which is not the same as my flutter project and thats the problem